# Libgdx: how to draw rectangle around group elements of Scene2D

Tags: java, libgdx, collision, scene2d

I want to know how to check collision between elements inside a group and other element of the games, in other word, I want to know how to draw a rectangle around elements of the group, cause so far every time I try, the rectangle is always in the wrong position, I tried using **stageToLocalCoordinates** but the result was always messed up (sometimes I get the rectangle in the correct position but when I move the group the rectangle seems to have a "mirror effect" {move in the opposite direction} )

Answer (score 0):

Use ShapeRenderer..

Make a function in all of your elements of the group that is returning a Rectangle.

```
public Rectangle getBounds()
{
return new Rectangle(x,y,width,height);
}
```

Now in the class with your stage, before drawing your elements (actors) draw the rectangle.

```
shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(stage.getCamera().combined);
shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.BLUE); // put any color you want
// for each actor of your stage do this
 shapeRenderer.rect(actor.getBounds().x,actor.getBounds().y,actor.getBounds().width,actor.getBounds().height);
```

Edit:

To convert a rectangle to a polygon you can use this method made by me some time ago

```
public static float[] rectangleToVertices(float x, float y, float width,
        float height) {
    float[] result = new float[8];
    result[0] = x;
    result[1] = y;

    result[2] = x + width;
    result[3] = y;

    result[4] = x + width;
    result[5] = y + height;
    result[6] = x;
    result[7] = y + height;

    return result;
}
```

And

```
Polygon poly=new Polygon(rectangleToVertices(.....));
```

Put your polygon in your gamescreen class.

In the render method set the polygon position..

Comment: "Make a function in all of your elements of the group that is returning a Rectangle." i can't find a way how to do that, all i can add to the group is an object of a type Image, for e.g, in my game i have a class called Paddle, this one is supposed to be a group Actor but i can't add an instance of it so i was forced to create a method that return an image and then add it to the group. thank you

Comment: in more details, what i meant is that if i do this : for (Actor ac : group.getChildren()) i can't later do ac.NameOfMethodInTheClassIBuild

Comment: Firstly, do you see your 'paddle' things on screen?  '//adding the actor (i don't know why i can't add the object itself)' you can't add your paddle object because is not an actor! your paddle class must extend actor read this tutorial http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2013/11/27/LibGDX-Tutorial-9-Scene2D-Part-1.aspx

Comment: i have tried to follow what you said (also i did know about the tutorial before, thnx) i have a new code http://pastebin.com/R43jqm96 but the result is "funny" like you can see in this GIF http://s4.postimg.org/bp4rmg159/group_Trble.gif thank you

Comment: Where is your code that moves your paddle? i think I need to see the groupUpdate(); method. and also why you don't do shape.rect(redPad.getBound().x, redPad.getBound().y, redPad.getBound().width, redPad.getBound().height); Don't forget to accept my answer if i've helped you!

Comment: the groupUpdate is the same of the 1st pastebin,  group.rotateBy(rotSpeed); and for your suggestion, that was the first thing i had in mind and when i tried it the rectangle is drawn in the 0,0 location (bottom left of the screen) and i believe that is because we must use the localToStageCoordinates method and i will surely do when the problem is 100% solved :-) thank you

Comment: The problem is that you can't rotate a rectangle, you will probably need to make a polygon and draw the polygon..and use polygon.setRotation(group.getRotation)  and you would also need to set the origin..to draw your polygon use shaperenderer.polygon(yourPolygon.getVertices()) I think

Comment: actually i don't want to rotate the rectangle, i want to rotate the group, and because the group element are not in the center of the group, rotating the group will cause the actors to change their position, what i need is that the rectangle to follow that position not the rotation

Comment: using the polygon is giving me the same result, just like the GIF above, here is how am doing it http://pastebin.com/CJN0Cerq however! if i change the groupUpdate method like the new one in the latest pastebin then everything seems to work even with the rectangle instead of the polygon, so the problem is with rotating the group, and the thing is that cannot let that go because what am trying to do is this http://bit.ly/1o7LSBd thank you

Comment: I'm not sure, but try to draw a rectangle that would have the coordinates from actor.getX() and actor.getY(), maybe use getChildren() to get the actors in the group, and use the first one in the array.

Comment: actually i think the problem is that i have an actor inside another actor (group) and then both go to the stage, because if i draw w shapeRenderer that take everything from the group (we can define origin and rotation in the shapeRenderer.rect) then i'll get perfectly what i want, the problem is that i cannot create a rectangle with a given rotation, which is very weird... and i don't know how to draw a rectangle using polygons and make it look to the right angle